# PHP & JavaScript - Variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just basically have a View with an Associative Array with Accidents Information.

The User will be able to **click in the Country**. When that happen I want to show them the information about accidents related with that country.

That information comes from *PHP* and the Click event is captured in *JQuery*...

> How Can I insert the `var country` inside the index of the
>   `associative array` that came from PHP with an Index for each country?

```
.on('click', function(i, row) {

        var country = row.label;

        accident_chart.setData([{
                a: <?php echo "".$charts['accidents_status'][**NEED var country value here**]['accidents']; ?>,
                y: 'Accidents',
            },
            {
                a: <?php echo $charts['accidents_status']['Qatar']['lost_time_accidents']; ?>,
                y: 'Lost Time',
            }
        ]);

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Use AJAX instead to get the accident_chart data.

```
.on('click', function(i, row) {

    var country = row.label;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_accident_chart", // Just replace it with your PHP controller function that can access your $charts variable
        data: {country: row.label},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        accident_chart.setData(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        return data;
        }
    });
});
```

In your PHP

```
get_accident_chart(){
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    $accident_chart = array(
        array(
            'a' => $charts['accidents_status'][$country]['accidents'],
            'y' => 'Accidents'
        ),
        array(
            'a' => $charts['accidents_status']['Qatar']['lost_time_accidents'],
            'y' => 'Lost Time'
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($accident_chart);
}
```